# $wpdb is queried but results don't show

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, mysql, wpdb

I am trying to show a list of custom post types on a page template. When I view the page, instead of seeing the different posts, I see the actual page repeated. For example, If I have 5 posts, the actual page (head content footer) will be display five times. It seems like the query is working...in some way but I am not sure what is wrong. Here is the template code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('page'); ?>>

        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        <article>

            <div class="post-content page-content">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php wp_link_pages('before=<div class="pagination">&after=</div>'); ?>
            </div><!--.post-content .page-content -->

        </article>

    </div><!--#post-# .post-->

<?php endwhile; ?>

<!-- Start search result code -->

<?php
//query_posts('post_type=listing&orderby=title&order=ASC&posts_per_page=9999');
?>

<?php
$querystr = "
SELECT * 
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postsmeta
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'listing_open' 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'YES'
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'listing'
ORDER BY post_title
";                              
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);                         
if ($pageposts):                    
foreach ($pageposts as $postdata):
setup_postdata($postdata);
?>

<?php //if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php include_once(get_bloginfo('template_url')."/layout-listings.php?id=".$postdata->ID); ?>       

<?php //endwhile; endif; rewind_posts(); wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php
endforeach;
endif;
?>

<?php
$querystr = "
SELECT * 
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'listing_open' 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'NO'
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'listing'
ORDER BY post_title
";                              
$pageposts2 = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);                            
if ($pageposts2):                    
foreach ($pageposts2 as $postdata2):
setup_postdata($postdata2);
?>

<?php //if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php include_once(get_bloginfo('template_url')."/layout-listings.php?id=".$postdata2->ID); ?>      

<?php //endwhile; endif; rewind_posts(); wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php
endforeach;
endif;
?>

<!-- End search result code -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the Codex page for [`setup_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata):

> Important: You must make use of the global $post variable to pass the post details into this function, otherwise functions like the_title() don't work properly...

Also note that you can use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to do these queries, rather than writing raw SQL.

Answer (score 0):

That is a lot of code to digest, but it looks like you are including the entire template with `include_once(get_bloginfo('template_url')."/layout-listings.php?id=".$postdata2->ID);`.  If that is the case, your probably are loading the whole page multiple times, though that `include_once` should be causing trouble. I am not sure why.

I am pretty sure you should be using [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) but it hard to say exactly how without more information.